Android sdk 34 java.lang.RuntimeException:Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created
After upgrading the Android SDK from version 33 to 34, the app crashes on Android 34, although it runs smoothly on Android 33.
the following changes have been made:
buildscript {
ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" 
    firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" 
    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 34
    targetSdkVersion = 34
    androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
    androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
    pdfViewer = "3.1.0-beta.1"
}

My current React Native version is 0.68.6.
Error in Android 34:
FATAL EXCEPTION: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.poi.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7716)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2478)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created
    at 


However, upon launching the application, I encountered an issue where the App Crashes immediately on the launch. To investigate this, I pulled a Bug Report, which provided the following insights:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created.
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: : One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts.
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace.


Luckily, I found a solution. For those who are still facing the above issue, please refer to the following
open your MainApplication.java file and add the below code.
First, import these lines
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

and make sure to add this code above the oncreate() method.
@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    } else {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}

add this line inside android/app/build.gradle dependencies.
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'

Now run your app. I hope it will work. Make sure to properly test.

I'm facing the same issue but the above solution doesn't work. Any extra configuration that you haven't mentioned in the above solution?

I've referred to the React Native Upgrade Helper, please check it there as you may have missed something

have you upgraded React native version or just following the mentioned version?

yes from 0.68 to 0.70
